# Hibernate get and load methods with lazy and eager fetch types

Tags: hibernate

What happens if i use Hibernate 'get' method for Entity that has 'Lazy' fetch type? or other way if i use 'load' method for Entity with 'Eager' fetch type? 
Does get and load methods work the same way in these cases?

Comment: What about get() and load() method of Hibernate, Is it related to lazy and Eager of Spring-data-JPA? @Rakesh Patil

Answer (score 1):

`FetchType.LAZY` = Doesn’t load the relationships unless explicitly “asked for” via getter
`FetchType.EAGER` = Loads ALL relationships

Comment: What about get() and load() method of Hibernate, Is it related to lazy and Eager of Spring-data-JPA? @developerbhuwan